# Ubuntu 20.04 gets stuck in the login loop

Tags: command-line, 20.04, bash, environment-variables

I can open the desktop using `startx` command in other tty

I have tried a lot of methods:

- chown the `Xauthority` file
- chmod the `/tmp`
- check the `/etc/environment` file

but all these methods do not work.

---

When I type `su root` command, it will give the following output:

[image: Screenshot of error]

```
bash: groups: command not found
Command 'lesspipe' is available in the following places
 * /bin/lesspipe
 * /usr/bin/lesspipe
The command could not be located because '/bin:/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
lesspipe: command not found
Command 'dircolors' is available in the following places
 * /bin/dircolors
 * /usr/bin/dircolors
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin:/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
dircolors: command not found
Command 'dirname' is available in the following places
 * /bin/dirname
 * /usr/bin/dirname
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin:/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
dirname: command not found
Command 'dirname' is available in the following places
 * /bin/dirname
 * /usr/bin/dirname
The command could not be located because '/bin:/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
dirname: command not found
Command 'dirname' is available in the following places
 * /bin/dirname
 * /usr/bin/dirname
The command could not be located because '/bin:/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
dirname: command not found
Command 'dirname' is available in the following places
 * /bin/dirname
 * /usr/bin/dirname
The command could not be located because '/bin:/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
dirname: command not found
```

when I type `groups, lesspipe, dirname`, these commands still work.

Comment: You should roll back to edit #4. Errors are better posted as text, because a search shot can not be searched for text.

Comment: This is the key:
"The command could not be located because '/bin:/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable."
You've somehow deleted or overwritten the default PATH variable.  To get back, first `export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin` and then try to find where you've overridden it (could be in .bashrc or /etc/environment or /etc/profile, etc.)

Comment: It's possible you've done more damage than that, but that will get you back to being able to make calls more easily, at least.